# Why and when does dataframe.apply give different results than using the function on an individual element?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to convert numpy.datetime64 to datetime.date.  Will you please tell me why method #2 works but not method #1?  Is it common for dataframe.apply(fn) to give a different result than calling fn(element)?

## 1

```
sample = np.datetime64('2018-03-31T00:00:00.000000000')
fails = pd.datetime.date(sample) 
# TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 
# 'numpy.datetime64'
```

## 2

```
sample = np.datetime64('2018-03-31T00:00:00.000000000')
sample = pd.DataFrame([sample])
print(sample[0].apply(pd.datetime.date))
```

pandas version: '0.23.3'

numpy version: '1.14.0'

Comment: I would not expect `fails = pd.datetime.date(sample)` to work tbh because you're not handling a dataframe but the error doesn't make sense to me; it's inconsistent behaviour unless I'm missing something (since `apply` should surely be using the same implementation)

Comment: The DataFrame constructor is casting your `datetime64` value to a `Timestamp`, from which it can apply `pd.datetime.date`. e.g. `pd.datetime.date(pd.Timestamp(sample))` works for `sample` as in your first case.

Comment: Hi Charles! Welcome to SO! To help people understand your problem, you can insert the error message or describe what you mean by it does not work.

Comment: Hi @BernardL, I put the error message in the comment at the bottom of code #1.  Where should I put it instead?  Is there a way to accept miradulo's comment as an answer?

Comment: No problem. Anything related to the question should be in the question itself and not in the comments. This helps people understand the question without going through all of the comments. @miradulo posted the solution in the comments which you will nt be able to accept, if you want, you can answer your own question for future users to view.

Comment: @CharlesFox You have added the information we need. He just didn't see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in the apply function.

As @miradulo explained in the comments, the DataFrame constructor casts datetime64 values to Timestamp.  pd.datetime.date(pd.Timestamp(sample)) works fine and is more comparable to method #2.